# C# consume rss feed containing xml-stylesheet?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-3.5, rss

I have a problem for parsing a rss feed using c#.
I used to use this method to load the feed.
XDocument rssFeed = XDocument.Load(@url);
But, when I notice when the feed has a xml-stylesheet this method crashes saying the xml is not well formated...
Here's a rss feed that contains this tag 
http://www.channelnews.fr/accueil.feed?type=rss

What would be the best way to parse any rss feed using c#?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works for me

```
    static XDocument DownloadPage()
    {
        var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.channelnews.fr/accueil.feed?type=rss");
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla";

        using(var response = req.GetResponse())
        using(var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            return XDocument.Load(reader);
    }
```

Note, that if you omit setting UserAgent, then response will contain string 'DOS' that is defnintly not xml :)

Comment: Yes it was this...I missed the UserAgent...
Thanks...
Stan

Answer (score 0):

This one works nicer:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("http://pedroliska.wordpress.com/feed/");

var items = from i in xdoc.Descendants("item")
            select new
            {
                Title = i.Element("title").Value
            };
```

So now you can access the rss titles by doing a loop or something like:

```
items[0].Title
```

And just the code is pulling the title from the rss feed, you can pull the description, link, pubDate, etc.

Comment: Remember to add the namespace to the XName delivered to `.Descendants` and `.Element`, or you might get 0 results. For Atom feeds this is static, so: `private static string XName(string elementName) { return string.Concat("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}", elementName); }`